# Role of known term in Routh - Hurwitz criterion, for $x^8 - 36·x^7 + 546·x^6 - 4536·x^5 + 22449·x^4 - 67284·x^3 + 118124·x^2 - 109584·x + 40321=0$.

Tags: polynomials

I was studying the sign of the solutions of this polynomial.
$$x^8 - 36·x^7 + 546·x^6 - 4536·x^5 + 22449·x^4 - 67284·x^3 + 118124·x^2 - 109584·x + 40321=0$$
I tried to apply the Routh-Hurwitz criterion, building the matrix:
$$\mathbf R (p) =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 546 & 22449& 118124 &40321\\
-36& -4536& -67284& 109584 & 0\\
b_{7} & b_{6} & \ldots  \\
c_{6} & c_{5} & &
\end{bmatrix} $$
But I noticed that the known term $40321$ plays no role in the determination of the coefficients in the first column. I have also noticed that polynomial can be rewritten as
$$(x - 1)·(x - 2)·(x - 3)·(x - 4)·(x - 5)·(x - 6)·(x - 7)·(x - 8) + 1=0$$
Since the known term $40321$ plays no role in the determination of the coefficients in the first column, I thought maybe we could ignore it (or part of it) and find the number of positive roots considering the following polynomial
$$x^8 - 36·x^7 + 546·x^6 - 4536·x^5 + 22449·x^4 - 67284·x^3 + 118124·x^2 - 109584·x + 40321-1=0$$
i.e.
$$(x - 1)·(x - 2)·(x - 3)·(x - 4)·(x - 5)·(x - 6)·(x - 7)·(x - 8)=0$$
that has all positive roots. Can I infer, then, that the original polynomial has exactly 8 positive roots?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). See [OEIS A$048994$](http://oeis.org/A048994) and [OEIS A$132393$](http://oeis.org/A132393).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $40321$ term does play a role in determining the first column. To properly apply the Routh Hurwitz criterion, you need to compute all $8+1 = 9$ rows of the Routh array, not just the first $4$ rows.

Here is the completed array (computed in Excel):

$\begin{bmatrix}
1& 546 & 22449 & 118124 & 40321\\
-36&-4536&-67284&-109584&0\\
420&20580&115080&40321&0\\
-2772&-57420&-106127.9143&0&0\\
11880&99000.01299&40321&0&0\\
-34319.99697&-96719.68095&0&0&0\\
65520.12047&40321&0&0&0\\
-75599.19784&0&0&0&0\\
40321&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$

As you can see, the $40321$ term does indeed play a role in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Wolfy's plot of the roots:

[image]

So the roots are pretty close to 1, 2, ..., 8.